# Need help identifying this type of search functionality and looking for ways to improve it

Tags: search

We are designing some tables for an application at work that can be lengthy at times. I was looking at what google does with its search functionality in Chrome by adding some visual markers to the right of any keywords that pertain to the search. I have been doing some research but I'm not sure if there is a name given for this functionality yet.

Does anyone know what this is called and do you have any thoughts or examples of any way to improve upon what Google is doing? There are code editors out there that do something similar and when you click on the tick it gives you more information as to where exactly the keyword is you are looking at. Google doesn't do this. I'm trying to gather as many examples as I can find.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is a example of what I am talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called *Annotated Scrollbar*. See [definition and 5 different usage examples from Quince](http://quince.infragistics.com/#/Search$tag=Navigation/ViewPattern$pattern=Annotated+Scrollbar&lang=en).

[Scrollbar markers](http://www.addictivetips.com/web/get-heading-markers-in-chrome-scrollbar-for-quick-navigation/) are another variation on this pattern.

Comment: Cool thanks for posting this. This is a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

This is called "Find on Page." I can't speak to improving it as it does set the expectation of where it could be.

Perhaps on the left, there is an excerpt instead of markers like in MS Word?

[image]

Comment: Thats an interesting idea. We have limited space. Maybe I can incorporate some sort of hybrid of this by showing row number and first column of text

Comment: If they are tables, what about using search as a filter to also reduce the rows to just what's been searched?

Comment: That's also a really good idea.